# P(X > a) > P(Y>a) -- does it imply P(X>Y) > 1/2?

Tags: probability

Given some real number $a$ can anyone prove that if
$$
P(X > a) > P(Y > a)
$$
is true then
$$
P(X > Y) > \frac12
$$
is also true.

Comment: It's definitely not true, I'll post a counterexample if no-one else does

Comment: Oh unless perhaps you mean for every real number $a$?

Comment: Number $a$ is given constant, let's say zero

Comment: How about "Does there exist a real number a s.t. ..." ?

Comment: @BCLC I am not sure I understand your hint, could you elaborate pls?

Comment: @lowtech Oh sorry it's not a hint. I was a suggesting another question. What if the 0.6 in T.Bongers' counterexample was lower? That is, how low does 0.6 have to brought down for the given X and Y in order for P(X>Y) > 0.5 to hold?

Comment: So does there exist a real number a s.t. P(X>a) > P(Y>a) implies P(X>Y)>0.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X$ takes value $1$ with probability $0.01$ and $0$ with probability $.99$.

$Y$ takes value $.5$ with probability $1$.

Then $P(X > .6) > 0 = P(Y > .6)$, while $P(X > Y)$ is $.01 < 1/2$.

Comment: thanks for this counterexample, i am still struggling with basic intuitions on probabilities...